# Memory consumption of WPF application in TaskManage

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I have created a WPF application, and my client asking me that the memory consumption increases in each and every action. He said he checked in TaskManager.(yeah I have checked as well).

I have checked for any memory leak using ANTS, and I am failed. I have already cleared memory leak issue in my application(well know, Memory leak and Memory consumption are different). But still the same Memory consumption increases for each and every operations, **say for example selecting an item in ListBox**

Here is the CS code which I have used.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBoxItem item = (PinnedListBox.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem);
        PinnedListBox.Items.Remove(item);
        UnPinnedListBox.Items.Add(item);
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBoxItem item1 = (UnPinnedListBox.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem);
        UnPinnedListBox.Items.Remove(item1);
        PinnedListBox.Items.Add(item1);
    }
```

On clicking Button1, the Item transfers from PinnedItems to UnPinned, and OnClick of Button2, item transfers from Unpinned to Pinned.

Someone please advice me regarding this.

Thanks in advance.

KSAM

Comment: Hello, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask . You should at least narrow your problem down to some suspicious part of your code, and then post this code here. It is imossible to debug your application, without seeing sources.

Comment: Increasing memory is not that unnormal for a managed c# application. AFAIK the garbage collector decides when to collect unused memory, until then it grows.

Comment: @Klaus78 making the control invisible? You do know that in WPF invisible controls are still there and consume memory, they can even receive events and depending on the visibility flag are positioned in the layout pass.

Comment: For how long did you observe the application's memory usage? Memory consumption may increase for quite a while before the garbage collector cleans up.

Comment: Thanks for your comments..... I am taking a closer look at this. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 1):

WPF applications use relatively large amount of memory compared to Winforms applications.
But even then, while yoour app is running, the OS will give it memory as it is needed by the app. At a certain moment, your app will do a garbage collect and basically memory is released.

You can do a simple trick to release some memory by minimizing your app.

see also: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-my/windows-vista/what-do-the-task-manager-memory-columns-mean